# What is the probability that store C makes more money than store A and B combined on any given day?

Tags: probability

I am working on a homework question:

Suppose we have three stores (store A, store B and store C), where store A has daily sales (in dollars) normally distributed by A ~ N(1100, 10000) (that is, the mean is 1100 and the variance is 10000), store B has daily sales (in dollars) normally distributed by B ~ N(1000, 5000) and store C has daily sales (in dollars) normally distributed by C ~ N(2000, 8000). Assume that the sales figures of the three stores are independent. What is the probability that store C makes more money than store A and B combined on any given day?

Comment: Maybe you can make a new variable, $Z= A+B-C$ and then see if it's negative.

Comment: Thanks for the tip